# How to write a bash script to store files from a directory to an output file?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to read in two arguments...a directory or a file and an output file. I need to compare the two to make sure they are different. If the first argument is a directory, then I need to store the files from that directory to the output file. If the first argument is a file then I need to store that file in the output file. Also, the first argument can contain white space in the middle as well as any files within that directory. The following is what I have so far. I am able to print out all the files within the directory, however, I am having trouble with the whitespace as well as storing the files within the directory or the file itself into the output file. How can I do this?

```
    #!/bin/bash

    INPUT="$1"
    OUTPUT="$2"

    # Check that there are two arguments
    if [ "$#" -ne 2]
    then
       echo "Usage: $0 {dir-name}"
       exit 1
    fi

    # Check that INPUT is different from OUTPUT
    if [ "$INPUT" = "$OUTPUT" ]
    then
       echo "$INPUT must be different from $OUTPUT!"
       exit 1
    fi

    # Check if INPUT is a directory
    if [ -d "$INPUT" ]
    then
       # Store all files from directory into OUTPUT file
       echo "$INPUT directory exists!"
       for name in `ls "$INPUT"`; do
          echo "File -> $name"
          mv "$name" "$OUTPUT"
       done
    fi

    # Check if INPUT is a file
    if [ -f "$INPUT" ]
    then
       # Move INPUT  into OUTPUT file
       echo "$INPUT file exists!" 
       mv "$INPUT" "$OUTPUT"
       exit 1
    else
       echo "$INPUT is not a file!"
       exit 1
    fi
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use a glob...

Comment: It appears you're clobbering your `$OUTPUT` by moving each file right on top of it. Perhaps look into `cat` and `>>`?

Comment: It also looks like you'll hit `echo "$INPUT is not a file!"` when it is a directory. Perhaps `exit` from within the `if[ -d "$INPUT" ]` or nest the file check in an `else`, and then you can say "$INPUT is neither a regular file nor a directory".

Comment: can you provide an example of the whitespace problem you are facing like what type of arguments you are passing to your script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This worked for me.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    INPUT="$1"
    OUTPUT="$2"

    # Check that there are two arguments
    if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]
    then
       echo "Usage: $0 {dir-name}";
       exit 1
    fi

    # Check that INPUT is different from OUTPUT
    if [ "$INPUT" = "$OUTPUT" ]
    then
       echo "$INPUT must be different from $OUTPUT!";
       exit 1
    fi

    # Check if INPUT is a directory
    if [ -d "$INPUT" ]
    then
       echo "$INPUT directory exists!";
       find $name -type f  > "$OUTPUT"
    # Check if INPUT is a file
    elif [ -f "$INPUT" ]
    then
       # Move INPUT  into OUTPUT file
       echo "$INPUT file exists!";
       find "$INPUT" > "$OUTPUT"
       exit 1
    else
       echo "$INPUT is not a file!";
       exit 1
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the below script solves the problem, i have replaced the for loop with a mv command so that you dont have to worry about the whitespacing between the files in the directory..

```
 #!/bin/bash

    INPUT="$1"
    OUTPUT="$2"

    # Check that there are two arguments
    if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]
    then
       echo "Usage: $0 {dir-name}"
       exit 1
    fi

    # Check that INPUT is different from OUTPUT
    if [ "$INPUT" = "$OUTPUT" ]
    then
       echo "$INPUT must be different from $OUTPUT!"
       exit 1
    fi

    # Check if INPUT is a directory
    if [ -d "$INPUT" ]
    then
       # Store all files from directory into OUTPUT file
       echo "$INPUT directory exists!"
       # The below command will solve the problem of file containing 
       # white space within the directory
       mv "$INPUT"/* "$OUTPUT"
    elif [ -f "$INPUT" ]
    then
       mv "$INPUT" "$OUTPUT"
    else
       echo "$INPUT is not a file!"
    fi
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work for what I'm trying to do...thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for name in "{$INPUT}"/*; do
      echo "File -> ${name}"
      cat "${name}" >> "${OUTPUT}"
done
```

This assumes that polarysekt's idea of `cat` works for you.  Otherwise, you'll need to manipulate `mv` or some other command into getting the output you're looking for.

As for having a space in a command-line argument (first argument or second), I don't see how `bash` can tell the difference between what is intended to be the first argument and the second, should a space be included, unless the argument is quoted.  In that case, again, try `"{$1}"` and `"{$2}"`.